# can't push notifications to ios using windowsazure

Tags: javascript, ios, azure-mobile-services

Im trying to use a script in the mobile services to push notifications to an ios mobile but I keep getting a script error in the logs although when adding a record from the mobile it is being added but the notification is not send,can someone help me with the error?
this is my script in the mobile services tab in azure of ios:

```
 function insert(item, user, request) {
 request.execute();
  // Set timeout to delay the notification, to provide time for the
    // app to be closed on the device to demonstrate toast notifications
    setTimeout(function() {
    push.apns.send(item.deviceToken, {
        alert: "Toast: " + item.text,
        payload: {
            inAppMessage: "Hey, a new item arrived: '" + item.text + "'"
        }
    },
  function (error) {
if (!error) {
  alert:"msg sent successfully"
}
});
 }, 2500);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the error to the log? Console.Log(error); What error are you receiving?

Comment: What is your script error?